# How to check for key-value pair mapping in this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, key-value

I want to define a structure that helps me maintain this key value pair list -

```
"ABC", "010"
"ABC", "011",
"BAC", "010"
"BAC" , "011"
"CAB", "020"
```

And then I want to write a method to pass in ("ABC" , "010" ) and see if this mapping exists & if it does the method returns true.

What structure should I use and how would the method look?

I tried -

```
 public bool IsAllowed(string source, string dest)
        {
            bool allowed = false;
            var allowedDest = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ABC","010"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ABC","011"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("BAC","010"),                
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("BAC","011"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CAB","020"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CAB","030")
            };

             // How to check for mapping?

            return allowed;
        }
```

Comment: How about this: `allowed = allowedDest.Any(c => c.Equals(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ABC", "010")));`

Comment: It feels like you just want to use a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Then check to see if value exists for a given key with `TryGetValue`; if that returns true, then the mapping exists.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a large list, I'd declare

```
HashSet<Tuple<string,string>> Allowed = new HashSet<Tuple<string,string>>();

Allowed.Add(Tuple.Create<string,string>("ABC","010");
[... and all the others]

if (Allowed.Contains(Tuple.Create<string,string>("ABC","010")) { }
```

If it's a small list, you can just iterate over it with a foreach statement or the .Any() command.

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep it simple and go with an array of string arrays.

```
public bool IsAllowed(string source, string dest)
{
    var allowedDest = new []
    {
        new [] {"ABC", "010"},
        new [] {"ABC", "011"},
        new [] {"BAC", "010"}
        //...
    };

    var match = new [] { source, dest };

    return allowedDest.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(match));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Linq methods here.

You can use FirstOrDefault method to retrieve item from the list with matching source and destination by comparing key and value of the items in the list.

If item found it will be returned else default of KeyValuePair will be returned.
Then you need to check if it returned default value or not and return true or false based on that.

```
public bool IsAllowed(string source, string dest)
    {
        bool allowed = false;
        var allowedDest = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ABC","010"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ABC","011"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("BAC","010"),                
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("BAC","011"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CAB","020"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CAB","030")
        };
        var item = allowedDest.FirstOrDefault(kvpair => kvpair.Key == source && kvpair.Value == dest);
        allowed = !item.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, string>));

        return allowed;
    }
```

This should help you resolve the issue.